# Zipping together unicode strings in Python

Tags: python, string, unicode, permutation

I have the string:

```
a = "ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜ" b = "àáâãäèéçêëìíîïòóôõöùúûüÿ"
```

and I want to create the string

```
"ÀàÁáÂâ..."
```

I.e split the string in two and then zip the halves together.

I tried the naive `zip(a, b)` but this didn't work.  I think this is due to a problem with unicode.

Does anyone know how I can get the result I want?

Comment: I thought someone asked which python version: python 2.7

Comment: @Nick, When I tried to zip then join the strings the output was 
`�À��Á��Â��Ã��È��É��Ê��Ë��Ì��Í��Î��Ï��Ò��Ó��Ô��Õ��Ö��Ù��Ú��Û��Ü�`

Comment: @BenPage In Python 2.7,be sure you declare your strings as unicode: either prefix strings with a `u`, or use `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2.x, strings are not unicode by default. When dealing with unicode data, you have to do the following:

- **prefix string literals with `u`** character: `a = u'ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜ'`, or
- if you want to avoid the `u` prefix and if the modules you are working with are enough compatible, **use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` import** to make string literals interpreted as unicode by default
- if you write unicode string literals directly in your Python code, **save your .py file in `utf-8` format** so that the literals are correctly interpreted. Python 2.3+ will interpret the [utf-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) ; a good practice is also to [add a specific comment line](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding) at the beginning of the file to indicate the encoding like `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, or
- you can also keep saving the .py file in `ascii`, but you will need to **escape the unicode characters in the literals**, which can be less readable: `'ÀÁÂÃ'` should become `'\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3'`

Once you fulfill those conditions, the rest is about applying algorithms on those unicode strings the same way you would work with the str version. Here is one possible solution for your problem with the `__future__` import:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from itertools import chain
a = "ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜ"
b = "àáâãäèéçêëìíîïòóôõöùúûüÿ"

print ''.join(chain(*zip(a,b)))

>>> ÀàÁáÂâÃãÈäÉèÊéËçÌêÍëÎìÏíÒîÓïÔòÕóÖôÙõÚöÛùÜú
```

Further references:

- [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) defines the non-ascii encoding comments
- [PEP 3120](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/) defines utf-8 as the default encoding in Python 3

Comment: Great, elaborate answer. I'd add a word about `#coding=` to the bullet #3.

Answer (score 3):

You have to join them up after you zip them, and also you need to define them as unicode strings:

```
>>>import itertools
>>>a = u"ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜ"
>>>b = u"àáâãäèéçêëìíîïòóôõöùúûüÿ"
>>>zipped = itertools.izip_longest(a,b, fillvalue="")
>>>print "".join(["".join(x) for x in zipped])

ÀàÁáÂâÃãÈäÉèÊéËçÌêÍëÎìÏíÒîÓïÔòÕóÖôÙõÚöÛùÜúûüÿ

>>>zipped = itertools.izip_longest(a,b, fillvalue="")
>>>print "".join(map("".join, zipped))

ÀàÁáÂâÃãÈäÉèÊéËçÌêÍëÎìÏíÒîÓïÔòÕóÖôÙõÚöÛùÜúûüÿ
```

Comment: I think I had a newbie mistake of not defining them as unicode strings and itertools.izip_longest will solve the lists being different sizes :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not beautiful, but working one.

```
>>> a_longer = len(a) > len(b)
>>> new_string = ""
>>> for i in range((min(len(a), len(b)))):
...     new_string += a[i] + b[i]
... 
>>> if a_longer:
...     new_string += a[i:]
... else:
...     new_string += b[i:]
... 
>>> print new_string
ÀàÁáÂâÃãÈäÉèÊéËçÌêÍëÎìÏíÒîÓïÔòÕóÖôÙõÚöÛùÜúúûüÿ
```

Or, with using zip:

```
>>> a = u'ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜ'
>>> b = u'àáâãäèéçêëìíîïòóôõöùúûüÿ'
>>> c = zip(a, b)
>>> new_string = "".join([a + b for a, b in c])
>>> print new_string
ÀàÁáÂâÃãÈäÉèÊéËçÌêÍëÎìÏíÒîÓïÔòÕóÖôÙõÚöÛùÜú
```

But watch out, that a zip method will not give you the rest of the 'b' string as it does not have a pair in 'a' string.

Comment: itertools.izip_longest will solve the lists being different sizes

Answer (score 0):

This is working on my side (Python 2.x):

```
>>> a = unicode('ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜ', 'utf-8')
>>> b = unicode('àáâãäèéçêëìíîïòóôõöùúûüÿ', 'utf-8')
>>> print ''.join([ ''.join(c) for c in zip(a, b)])
ÀàÁáÂâÃãÈäÉèÊéËçÌêÍëÎìÏíÒîÓïÔòÕóÖôÙõÚöÛùÜú
```

What error do you have?

Comment: when i tried to use the unicode function ( I wasn't adding the 'utf-8' param, i got `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`
but if i define the string as u"..." it works. :)