# Python GAE unicode literals not properly decoded after deployment

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, unicode

I am building an app running on GAE which receives input from users via webform:

```
myUnicodeString = cgi.escape(self.request.get('myForm'))
```

It all works fine locally but after deployment unicode literals are converted into strings of the form: "E2=80=9C no problems with ASCII strings"
Having read Nick's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766472/google-app-engine-textproperty-and-utf-8-when-to-encode-decode) not to use cgi.escape I was wondering that it might be the culprit.
I have also tried adding

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989860/python-unicode-string-operation-in-app-engine-failing) but then the program throws an error (TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode) which is apparently triggered by webapp2_extras session

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
I have noticed that this decoding/encoding issue has something to do with the text input fields submitted in the same form as the file uploaded to the blobstore. No problems occur while I save the same non ASCII strings via separate forms or via ajax.

UPDATE2:
[This](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749) is apparently the bug that causes the problem.

Comment: Did you read Nick's answer at the same place he posted that comment?  That has everything you need to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Engine TextProperty and UTF-8: When to Encode/Decode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766472/google-app-engine-textproperty-and-utf-8-when-to-encode-decode)

Comment: The thing is that when I use bottle framework on GAE I don't encounter any problems with request.get after deployment. As mentioned above I everything is fine with the code running on webapp2 but only locally.